# How to append multiple elements as values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Lets say i have a dictionary:

```
favorittForfattere={'Per':'Christie','Kari':'Ibsen', \
 'Liv':'Rowling','Ola':'Ibsen', \
'Anne':'Allende', 'Jens':'Christie'}
```

With this dictionary i want to create a function where i get the keys and values from that dictionary, and then append them in to a new dictionary which gets created during the function.  the values of the previous dictionary will be keys in the new dictionary. the keys from the previous dictionary will be values in the new dictionary.

The expeted outcome would be this

```
{'Christie': ['Per', 'Jens'], 'Ibsen': ['Kari', 'Ola'], 'Rowling': ['Liv'], 'Allende': ['Anne']}
```

This is my code so far

```
def fans(favorittForfattere):
    nyFortegnelse = {}
    for keys, values in favorittForfattere.items():
        nyFortegnelse.update({values:keys})
    print(nyFortegnelse)
```

How would i solve this problem?

This is the whole code snip so it makes sence

```
favorittForfattere={'Per':'Christie','Kari':'Ibsen', \
 'Liv':'Rowling','Ola':'Ibsen', \
'Anne':'Allende', 'Jens':'Christie'}

def fans(favorittForfattere):
    nyFortegnelse = {}
    for keys, values in favorittForfattere.items():
        nyFortegnelse.update({values:keys})
    print(nyFortegnelse)

fans(favorittForfattere)
```

Comment: Try: 
`nyFortegnelse.update({values:[keys]})`

Comment: This specific duplicate servers for duplicate values - the one itself links to has answers for unique and duplicate values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dict.setdefault` with value as list.

**Ex:**

```
favorittForfattere={'Per':'Christie','Kari':'Ibsen', 'Liv':'Rowling','Ola':'Ibsen', 'Anne':'Allende', 'Jens':'Christie'}

def fans(favorittForfattere):
    nyFortegnelse = {}
    for key, value in favorittForfattere.items():
        nyFortegnelse.setdefault(value, []).append(key)
    print(nyFortegnelse)

fans(favorittForfattere)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Allende': ['Anne'],
 'Christie': ['Per', 'Jens'],
 'Ibsen': ['Kari', 'Ola'],
 'Rowling': ['Liv']}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! i will put this as the answer as soon as i can put an answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
favorittForfattere={'Per':'Christie','Kari':'Ibsen','Liv':'Rowling','Ola':'Ibsen','Anne':'Allende', 'Jens':'Christie'}
dictionary={}
for i in favorittForfattere:
    if favorittForfattere[i] not in dictionary:
        dictionary[favorittForfattere[i]]=[]
    dictionary[favorittForfattere[i]].append(i)
```

output:

```
{'Christie': ['Per', 'Jens'],
 'Ibsen': ['Kari', 'Ola'],
 'Rowling': ['Liv'],
 'Allende': ['Anne']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
def fans(favorittForfattere):
    nyFortegnelse = {}
    for k, v in favorittForfattere.items():
        nyFortegnelse[v] = nyFortegnelse.get(v, [])
        nyFortegnelse[v].append(k)
    return nyFortegnelse
```